# Why Laravel middleware works for single routes but not group of routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cross-domain, cors, middleware

I have added a CORS middleware and it works fine for single routes :-

```
Route::get('example', ['middleware' => 'cors', function(){
    return Response::json(array('name' => 'Steve Jobs', 'company' => 'Apple'));
}]);
```

But when I apply it to group of routes, it gives error in console :-

```
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://jotdot.mysite.com/api/authenticate. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control 
check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on 
the requested  resource. Origin 'http://jotdotfrontend.mysite.com' is
therefore not allowed access.
```

My group of routes :-

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});
});
```

Cors.php

```
class CORS
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

I am following https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps and trying to set up backend and frontend on different domains.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that route-based middleware were never applied on `OPTIONS` request for autogenerated `resource`-based routes ('cause `Route::resource(...)` doesn't generate routes for `options` method?).

So, put yours `cors` middleware inside global middleware group in `app/Http/Kernel.php`, just before `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware:

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Ankh\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class, // here it is
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];
```

And entirely remove it from `routes.php`, like:

```
// Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});
//});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'cors'], function()
{
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});
```

Comment: @StacyJ I think the problem is when you try to send a **POST** request, then Laravel will verify the `CsrfToken`. Take a look at [Laravel Csrf protection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection). You need disable this middleware in `Kernel.php` file at `line 20` to resovle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CORS'], function() {
     Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
     Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');

});
```

Comment: How can I add midlleware to respective routes inside the group?

Answer (score 0):

Your origin header isn't in your headers array. Instead of setting your origin header using header(), try adding it with your other access control headers like this:

```
// ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
$headers = [
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'=> '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
];
```